# Path-analyzer showing the Web API request

Tags: webapi, path-analyzer

Sitecore : 9.1 + JSS 11.0 Integrated mode

What we have:
We have written certain APIs in our Sitecore solution. The front-end code access those APIs on the page-load.
In the Path-analyzer, we see the entries for these API requests, and we want to get rid of them.

What we did:
We wrote a custom pipeline over-ridding `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeTracker.CreatePage`. In the Sitecore code, they look for the referenced item. So, we put an extra check for `ItemId`. But it was of no avail. Our custom code is as below:

```
public class CustomCreatePage : InitializeTrackerProcessor
  {

    private ILogger _logger = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger)) as InsightsLogger;
    public override void Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
    {
      try
      {
        if (args.IsSessionEnd)
        {
          return;
        }
        HttpContextBase httpContext = args.HttpContext;
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
          args.AbortPipeline();
          return;
        }
        this.CreateAndInitializePage(args.Session.Interaction);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        _logger.WriteException(ex);
      }
    }

    private void CreateAndInitializePage(CurrentInteraction visit)
    {
      IPageContext empty = visit.CreatePage();
      empty.SetUrl(WebUtil.GetRawUrl());
      DeviceItem device = Context.Device;
      if (device == null)
      {
        empty.SitecoreDevice.Id = Guid.Empty;
        empty.SitecoreDevice.Name = string.Empty;
      }
      else
      {
        empty.SitecoreDevice.Id = device.ID.Guid;
        empty.SitecoreDevice.Name = device.Name;
      }

      // Default Sitecore implementation
      Item item = Context.Item;

      // Our logic starts here: if the request is of the API (Account feature)
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item?.ID?.ToString()))
      {
        item = null;
      }



      HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString());
      // Resume the default behaviour
      if (item == null)
      {
        return;
      }

      empty.SetItemProperties(item.ID.Guid, item.Language.Name, item.Version.Number);
    }
  }
```

Please guide us on what we should do.